# Use python with orientDB and gremlin-server

Tags: python, orientdb, gremlin-server, gremlinpython

I want to deploy orientDB graph using gremlin-server, and connect it with python using gremlin_python library.

I downloaded `orientDB with gremlin server - zip` community edition

I am able to deploy orientDB by running `bin\server.bat` , but there is no `gremlin-server.bat` (or `.sh`) available to deploy orientDB with gremlin-server.

I had previously downloaded tinkerpop gremlin-server, and tried running that with gremlin-server.yaml file available in orientDB.

Some version info :

```
OrientDB : orientdb-tp3-3.0.2
Tinkerpop : apache-tinkerpop-gremlin-server-3.3.1
Gremlin_python : gremlinpython==3.3.2
```

The versioning may be an issue. But I also want to know how to set this up. Was my good enough, and I just need to correct the versions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it's always preferred to have the same version.

For OrientDB side you can download the OrientDB with Gremlin Server edition
There is no gremlin-server.bat since there is a plugin inside that spawn the GremlinServer when OrientDB boot up. For now OrientDB Ships GremlinServer 3.3.0

Alternatively you can install the OrientDB Gremlin driver in a Gremlin Server

You can find some docs about this here

https://orientdb.com/docs/3.0.x/tinkerpop3/OrientDB-TinkerPop3.html#gremlin-server

Comment: I have successfully connected to orientdb but now, getting a `gremlin_python.driver.protocol.GremlinServerError: 401: Username and/or password are incorrect` error when trying to run gremlin queries via gremlin-python

Comment: By default if you use the OrientDB Tp3 edition, the embedded gremlin server is protected with OrientDB root credentials. You should use those credentials from the python side or remove that protection by removing the authenticator from the yaml file.

Answer (score 0):

```
from gremlin_python.process.anonymous_traversal import traversal

from gremlin_python.driver.driver_remote_connection import DriverRemoteConnection

from gremlin_python.structure.graph import Graph

graph = Graph()
g = graph.traversal().withRemote(DriverRemoteConnection('ws://localhost:8182/gremlin','g', username = "root",password="root_password"))
```

Works for me

Comment: This says nothing about the setup of the orientdb and gremlin-server. I'll upvote if you supply this information since i'd like to use it in http://wiki.bitplan.com/index.php/Gremlin_python#Connecting_to_Gremlin_enabled_graph_databases.